# Can't connect to my ejabberd server using Asmack

Tags: android, keystore, ejabberd, asmack, sasl

Getting these errors in logcat:

06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261): java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261):     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:858)
06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:250)
06-26 02:34:08.352: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:46)
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:72)
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261): Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261):     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:177)
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261):     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:151)
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261):     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
06-26 02:34:08.362: W/System.err(1261):     ... 5 more

06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261): SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5: 
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:341)
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:242)
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:371)
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at com.example.contactupdater.MainActivity$MainActivity2.login(MainActivity.java:358)
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at com.example.contactupdater.MainActivity$MainActivity2.login(MainActivity.java:347)
06-26 02:34:09.802: W/System.err(1261):     at com.example.contactupdater.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:320)

Comment: Please show us the code you use to connect to ejabberd and which Asmack version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your response mate but i have solved this problem by adding keystore path. will add answer. Thanks

Comment: @Punit please post answer, i m facing same problem..

Comment: @shriduttkothari Please check out my answer. and sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for this problem...

```
AndroidConnectionConfiguration config = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(server,
                port);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            config.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
            config.setTruststorePassword(null);
            config.setTruststorePath(null);
        } else {
            config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
            String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
            if (path == null)
                path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc"
                    + File.separator + "security" + File.separator
                    + "cacerts.bks";
            config.setTruststorePath(path);
        }
```

Comment: good work , but this will remove key store error what about "SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5".I am still facing this error after adding your solution in my code...hope you will answer soon!!!!

Comment: i am facing error while try to log in , here is stack trace  SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5: 
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:341)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:242)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:371)
  at       any idea what is problem here !!!

Comment: are you using jid as JID@domain.com ? if yes please remove @domain.com like if you have abc@domain.com then only use abc as user name.